# React onBlur detect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onblur

I have two react components, one is to display the name and the circle and another is a sidebar. When I click the circle component, the sidebar will show. And when I click the outside of the circle component, the sidebar will be hidden.

I was set a onBlur to the circle component, so when I click outside of the element, the sidebar will be hidden.

However, there is a problem in this way that when I switch from Name A to Name B, the sidebar will be hidden first and then show.

Is there a way I can keep the sidebar open when I switch from Name A to Name B and the sidebar will be open if I click outside of the circle element without swtich?

The below is part of my code logic:

For the circle component:

```
const handleParticipantOnClick = () => {
    dispatch(oepnSidebar())
}

const handleParticipantOnBlur = () => {
    dispatch(closeSidebar())
}

<div onBlur={handleParticipantOnBlur} onClick={handleParticipantOnClick}>
    <ProgressRing/>
</div>
```

The sidebar will be show/close based on the method dispatch, that action only update the open status of the sidebar.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS - How to get onFocus and onBlur to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46896776/reactjs-how-to-get-onfocus-and-onblur-to-work)

Answer (score 0):

here is what I do to resolve this:

1. Assign all the Name components to a Ref (the ref will be a list)
2. onBlur function will check if user clicking on other names or not, if not, go ahead and close the sidebar, if yes, do nothing.

Code Sandbox example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-bash-2slgm?file=/src/App.js

you can comment on the code from lines 19 to 21 to see the difference.

Hope this helps :D